# Update iOS Google Maps mapStyle on environment colorScheme change (dark mode)

Tags: swift, swiftui, google-maps-sdk-ios

When changing device settings between light mode and dark mode my Google Maps mapStyle is not updating. The other views successfully toggle to the selected mode, it's just the map that doesn't change.

The mapStyle does change correctly when my app is restarted.

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

  @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

  private let mapView = GMSMapView(frame: .zero)
  private let defaultZoomLevel: Float = 10

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> GMSMapView {
    
    mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
    applyColorSchemeToMap()
  
    return mapView
  }

  func updateUIView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, context: Context) {
    
    applyColorSchemeToMap()
  }
  
  func applyColorSchemeToMap() {
    do {
      if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: colorScheme == .dark ? "night_map_style" : "map_style", withExtension: "json") {
        mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
      } else {
        NSLog("Unable to find style.json")
      }
    } catch {
      NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. MapView must conform to UIViewControllerRepresentable, not UIViewRepresentable.

A guide on how to achieve this (using a ViewControllerBridge) can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/codelabs/maps-platform/maps-platform-ios-swiftui#0

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way for you:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    var body: some View {

        MapView(colorScheme: colorScheme)
        
    }
}



struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    var colorScheme: ColorScheme
    private let mapView = GMSMapView(frame: .zero)
    private let defaultZoomLevel: Float = 10

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> GMSMapView {

        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        applyColorSchemeToMap()

        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, context: Context) {
        applyColorSchemeToMap(colorScheme: colorScheme)
    }

    func applyColorSchemeToMap(colorScheme: ColorScheme) {
        do {
            if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: (colorScheme == .dark) ? "night_map_style" : "map_style", withExtension: "json") {
                mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
            } else {
                NSLog("Unable to find style.json")
            }
        } catch {
            NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That hasn't seemed to change anything. I am testing on the simulator rather than a physical device. Don't know if that affects anything?